# Как Найти директорию домена на centos7?

Tags: linux

Как в centOS7 узнать в какой директории располагается сайта mysite.com?
Не получается никак найти сайт

Comment: см. содержимое конфигурационных файлов используемого http-сервера.

Comment: Ну если не смотреть конфиги, то сначала стоит поискать глазами в `/var/www` и в `/home`.